# How do I get the milliseconds from epoc till starting of today's?

Tags: java, android, datetime

I am trying to get the today's time in millisecond for the start of the day.I have created a method for it but it's returning me the wrong result:

```
private void getCurrentMillisecondsTime() {
        // get calendar instance, substitute timezone for which ever you need or
        // leave blank to use current
        Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // set hour
        updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); // set minute
        updateTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // set seconds

        long time = updateTime.getTimeInMillis(); // get milliseconds
        System.out.println(updateTime.getTime());
        System.out.println(time);
    }
```

**The output of above code is :**

```
I/System.out(30191): Mon Jun 30 00:00:00 GMT+06:00 2014
I/System.out(30191): 1404064800894
```

**But I want it to be :**

```
1404066600000
```

I think its the problem of timezone which I don't know how to fix.

Comment: `updateTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);` ?

Comment: @assylias That didn't work either.I am getting the same result as I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The start of today is obviously dependent on the time zone. Based on your expectation of `1404066600000`, you are looking at a 5.5 hour offset from UTC, which would probably be India's timezone.

So you would need something like:

```
Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // set hour
updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); // set minute
updateTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // set seconds
updateTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); // set milliseconds

long time = updateTime.getTimeInMillis(); // get milliseconds
System.out.println(updateTime.getTime());
System.out.println(time);
```

which outputs (my timezone is BST = British Summer Time):

```
Sun Jun 29 19:30:00 BST 2014
1404066600000
```

Comment: I feel this answer is incomplete without advice to use one of the numerous DateUtil classes and/or JodaTime.

Comment: @Ordous: Why add a 3rd party library to solve such a trivial problem?

Comment: @jarnbjo For one problem - that would be stupid. But problems with dates don't normally come isolated.

Comment: @Ordous The principle would be the same with alternative date apis and the code with the legacy API is not that bad in this case, so I did not feel like it would add much to recommend alternatives. Feel free to add an answer if you disagree.

Answer (score 0):

I have written this method which does what you are looking for without creating costly Calendar objects

```
public static long getStartOfDay(long t) {
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    t +=tz.getOffset(t);
    t -= (t % 86400000);
    t -= tz.getOffset(t);
    return t;
}
```

To get the time in millisecond for the start of today you could do this

```
getStartOfDay(System.currentTimeMillis());
```